# Using tab key to advance to next file in Finder for numerically ordered files

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

I have a directory of files named like:

```
it(0).png
it(1).png
it(2).png
...
it(10).png
it(11).png
...
```

In Finder my directory is arranged by Name and the files are in correct numerical order. I like to use <kbd>space</kbd> preview to view the files, then I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to advance, but the selection advances in alphabetical (ASCII?) order rather than numeric:

```
it(0).jpg -> 1 -> 10 -> ... -> 19 -> 2 -> 21 -> ...
```

Is there a way to advance in the numeric order that Finder displays the files in? I am on OS X Mavericks 10.9.3

To reproduce run this in Terminal.app

```
mkdir /tmp/alphanum && for i in {0..29}; do touch /tmp/alphanum/$i; done && open /tmp/alphanum
```

Select the first item and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as they are all named following the same format (test1.jpg, test2.jpg etc.) you'll get the behavior you're looking for. <kbd>tab</kbd> will advance you alphabetically. <kbd>Down</kbd> will advance you now the list in the order the files are currently displayed in the finder window.

Comment: This is incorrect, see updated question.

Comment: Ah. I see what you're asking now. tab is alphabetically-strict, not numerically. It's just taking the first character in the string for the filename. You're asking finder to advance through a directory in the order `a -> b -> ab` rather than `a -> ab -> b` (analogous to `1 -> 10 -> 2`). It still looks like Finder is ordering the files 1, 2, 3 to me. Does the Down button not work for you here?

Comment: Yeah I get that I want it in natural order rather than alphabetical. The down button won't help either, as that will move down to the next row not advance to the next one. I am asking how to advance in the order which Finder displays.

Comment: Ah. I see. I'm assuming you have your icons arranged in grid view, I use list view with the quickview frame. Try the Right arrow key. This should move you right-to-left then top-to-bottom in the order displayed.

Comment: So a possible answer could be to switch to list view and use down.

Comment: Correct, or the right arrow key staying in grid view. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Right arrow won't work in gridview, it will get to the end of the row and advance no further.

Comment: Interesting. You're quite right, of course; I will add that the Down key will advance you in the order shown in finder in List, Column, and Cover Flow view, while both the Right and Down arrow keys produce the result you're looking for in Cover Flow view.